# Как правильно подключить библиотеку C++ в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, библиотеки

Скачал библиотеку из интернета. Внутри более 500 файлов *.h* и *.cpp*.

Я сначала подумал нужно включить все файлы из библиотеки в проект. И в общем то всё работает, только дерево файлов в Visual Studio превратилось в мусор. И я так понял, что сделал что-то не так.

Как правильно подключить библиотеку к проекту? Возможно есть более правильный способ, вместо включения всех исходников в проект?

Comment: Соберите библиотеку отдельно (подробности в документации к ней) и подключайте к проекту как `.lib` или `.dll`.

Comment: Почитал документацию - собрать библиотеку в `.lib` нельзя.
Насчёт `.dll` - я так понял мне придётся всю библиотеку перелопатить и ставить перед всеми функциями `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: @JaminPeru Только для интерфейсный функций (API библиотеки)

Comment: Собрать в `.lib` нельзя? Это нонсенс, в `.lib` собрать можно что угодно. Дайте ссылку.

Comment: @PinkTux [может я неправильно понял](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840628/building-bullet-physics-as-shared-libraries)?

Comment: @free_ze что это значит?

Comment: @JaminPeru Интерфейс библиотеки, т.е. те функции, которые вы планируете вызывать кодом извне. Какие-то сугубо внутренние "кишки" библиотеки, вспомогательные функции экспортировать не нужно.

Comment: Да, это ж надо так учудить - "no symbols are explicitly exported" :-) А как собрать dll там написано.

Comment: @PinkTux, ничего удивительного, если библиотека разрабатывалась под Unix, а в Windows просто сделали порт.

Comment: Вам нужно собрать статическую версию библиотеки(я так понял, она по умолчанию соберёт как разе её). Затем добавить в проект студии пути до заголовочных файлов этой библиотеки и, наконец, подключить полученный lib файл в проект.

Comment: @ixSci, речь об [этом](http://bulletphysics.org/) - не очень понятно, почему именно так...

Comment: @PinkTux, да, я понял. Я переходил по ссылке. Просто для UNIX систем не надо ничего явно указывать, насколько я знаю. А для Windows надо помечать всё, что собираешься экспортировать/импортировать. Поэтому, если они разрабатывали библиотеку для UNIX и у них получилась большая база, то я прекрасно их понимаю, что никто не хочет теперь в неё добавлять тонну `declspec`

Comment: @ixSci так я не понял, значит мне всё таки собирать библиотеку в `.lib`?

Comment: @JaminPeru, lib, в windows, нужен всегда. Просто у него может быть разное содержимое. В случае статической сборки там весь нужный код, тогда как при сборке dll в lib лежит лишь информация для последующего импорта, которая генерируется на основании того, что код экспортирует.

Comment: @ixSci, ах, я понял. спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно с библиотекой - тем более такой большой - идет описание, как ее скомпилировать и собрать в библиотечный файл (это может быть один .lib для статической линковки, или, скажем, .dll и .lib для динамической).

Обычно все h-файлы кладчтся в какой-то каталог, путь к которому указывается в настройках проекта, ну, и в проекте же указывается, какой библиотечный файл подключать.

Comment: Я это уже понял благодаря комментариям, но спасибо вам за то что подытожили.